# SQL Server Log out / Terminate session of logged in user in a query

Tags: sql-server

Without going into why I would like to do this, is it possible (I'll be using a login trigger) to log out a user that has no write permissions to a certain database?

I am able to find the currently logged in users permission, I just need to know if it's possible to log them out?

```
DECLARE @HasPermission bit

SELECT @HasPermission =  HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME('RTEST2.dbo.TestTableSize', 'OBJECT', 'INSERT');

IF @HasPermission = 0
   SELECT 'Now this is where id want to log out the user'
```

Comment: Just execute `ROLLBACK` in the login trigger.

Comment: Dan's right (`THROW` should also work) -- but make very, very sure to test this on a completely separate instance. A bad login trigger that blocks even admins can be particularly annoying to recover from.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - thanks. I just had flashbacks to the last time I had to work out how the DAC works.

Comment: @DanGuzman That worked great thank. Mind if you add it as an answer so I can Mark it?

Comment: Please also put a RAISERROR or PRINT statement in the trigger body to record in the SQL Server Log the reason for the logon failure.  The client will never get those details, but they are useful to have in the log for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can prevent a user from logging in by executing a `ROLLBACK` from within a [login trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/logon-triggers). As @DavidBrowneMicrosoft mentioned in his comment, it's also a good practice to use a `PRINT` or `RAISERROR` statement so that reason for the login failure is logged. This message will not be returned to the client but may be useful for troubleshooting.

```
IF @HasPermission = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'User does not have permissions to login';
    ROLLBACK;
END;
```